# Combine multiple columns into vector by row with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to combine multiple columns into a single cell for each row and then remove missing values.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 b=c(NA, "a", "b", "c"),
                 c=c("a", "b", "e", "g"))
```

Attempt:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
mutate(collapse=as.character(paste(a,b,c, collapse=",")),
       collapse_nona=na.omit(collapse))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a     b     c     collapse                collapse_nona         
* <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>                   <chr>                 
1 a     NA    a     a NA a,b a b,c b e,d c… a NA a,b a b,c b e,d …
2 b     a     b     a NA a,b a b,c b e,d c… a NA a,b a b,c b e,d …
3 c     b     e     a NA a,b a b,c b e,d c… a NA a,b a b,c b e,d …
4 d     c     g     a NA a,b a b,c b e,d c… a NA a,b a b,c b e,d …
```

1) I am not successfully creating cells with values for each row (the whole column appears in collapse).

2) Cells in the collapse column do not behave like a vector.

Desired output

```
  a     b     c     collapse                collapse_nona         
* <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>                   <chr>                 
1 a     NA    a     a NA a                  a a
2 b     a     b     b a b                   b a b
3 c     b     e     c b e                   c b e
4 d     c     g     d c g                   d c g
```

Thank you

Comment: Try with`unite` `df %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% unite(collapse, a, b,c, na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE, sep=" ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `unite`, there is an option for `na.rm` and it is by default FALSE

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_all(as.character) %>%
   unite(collapse, a, b,c,  remove = FALSE, sep=" ") %>%
   unite(collapse_nona, a, b, c, remove = FALSE, sep=" ", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   select(names(df), everything())
#   a    b c collapse collapse_nona
#1 a <NA> a   a NA a           a a
#2 b    a b    b a b         b a b
#3 c    b e    c b e         c b e
#4 d    c g    d c g         d c g
```

---

Or with `paste` and `str_remove_all` (from `stringr`) - Note that `paste/str_c` are vectorized, so there is no need to loop over each row with `rowwise`

```
df %>%
     mutate(collapse = paste(a, b, c), 
            collapse_nona = str_remove_all(collapse,  "\\sNA|NA\\s"))
#  a    b c collapse collapse_nona
#1 a <NA> a   a NA a           a a
#2 b    a b    b a b         b a b
#3 c    b e    c b e         c b e
#4 d    c g    d c g         d c g
```

---

Another option is `pmap` to loop over each row, remove the `NA` elements with `na.omit` and then `paste` or `str_c` (from `stringr`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
     mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
     mutate(collapse_nona = pmap_chr(., ~ c(...) %>%
                na.omit %>%
                str_c(collapse=" "))) 
#  a    b c collapse_nona
#1 a <NA> a           a a
#2 b    a b         b a b
#3 c    b e         c b e
#4 d    c g         d c g
```

Comment: Any advice on flagging cells with non identical entries in collapse_nona? So rows 2,3&4 get flagged because not all entries are the same.

Comment: @EML your 2nd rows have two 'b' elements

Comment: @EML Do you need `df %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% mutate(flag = pmap_lgl(., ~  n_distinct(na.omit(c(...))) > 1)  )`

Comment: I mean, if at least one element is different, then the row is flagged.

Comment: @EML ok, in that case, the code in the comment should work

Comment: @EML Or aftter the unite step `df %>%
    mutate_all(as.character) %>%
    unite(collapse, a, b,c,  remove = FALSE, sep=" ") %>%
    unite(collapse_nona, a, b, c, remove = FALSE, sep=" ", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    select(names(df), everything()) %>% mutate(flag = map_lgl(str_extract_all(collapse_nona, "[a-z]+"), ~ n_distinct(.) > 1))`

Answer (score 2):

The think the core issue is that you don't want `collapse`, you want `sep`. Then rowwise calculation is unnecessary. Also, `NA` will get printed as character, so you cannot remove them with `na.omit`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(collapse = paste(a,b,c, sep = " "), collapse_nona = gsub("NA", "", collapse))

  a    b c collapse collapse_nona
1 a <NA> a   a NA a          a  a
2 b    a b    b a b         b a b
3 c    b e    c b e         c b e
4 d    c g    d c g         d c g
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it. You could play around with the sep argument in str_c.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(collapse = str_c(str_replace_na(a), str_replace_na(b), str_replace_na(c), sep = " "),
         collapse_nona = str_c(str_replace_na(a, ""), str_replace_na(b, ""), str_replace_na(c,""), sep = " "))

  a    b c collapse collapse_nona
1 a <NA> a   a NA a          a  a
2 b    a b    b a b         b a b
3 c    b e    c b e         c b e
4 d    c g    d c g         d c g
```